# cant select an option on internet connection screen when installing windows on virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install a copy of windows 10 home on my virtual machine using hyper-v. when I got to this screen (internet connection screen) I was unable to select anything, help? https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMsoC.png

Answer (score 0):

Please choose "I don't have internet".

[image]

Comment: when I click it nothing happens?

Comment: After clicking, it should appear "There’s more to discover when you connect to the internet".

Comment: but i cant click on it, what im trying to say is that it isnt a button. almost as im clicking on a picture.